# Fading in an answer after the submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I fad in an answer underneath a question after the submit button is clicked? For example I would like the correct answer to a question to appear only after the submit button is clicked.

```
<p class="question">1.What is the capital of Greece?</p>
<input id="q1a" type="radio" name="q1" value="a" /><label for="q1a"> Patras</label>
<input id="q1b" type="radio" name="q1" value="b" /><label for="q1b"> Athens</label>

<center><input class="button" onclick="getResults()" type="submit" value="Submit" />


<strong>Question 1:</strong> The correct answer is Athens.
```

Comment: Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3KAQP/) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the answer in a div for example and hide it (you can hide it with div.style.display = 'none';)

After, use fadeIn on the div on the event of the submit button.